# Is there a way to select multiple time invervals in a single xarray dataset

Tags: python-xarray

I have a xarray dataset that contains sensor samples from 9-5-2021 5am to 17-5-2021 12:20pm and the sampling period is 10Hz.

I would like to extract information from
5am-520am, 9am-920am , 1pm-120pm , 4-420pm... (4 hour time between intervals for 20 minutes each).

So far I know that the following code
selects that one time interval:

`file_dataset.sel(time = slice('2021-05-09T0:05:00','2021-05-09T0:05:20'))`

I sort of want to do this but I know it does not work:

`file.sel(time = (slice('2021-05-09T0:05:00','2021-05-09T0:05:20'), slice('2021-05-09T0:09:00','2021-05-09T0:09:20')...slice('2021-05-17T0:12:00','2021-05-17T0:12:20'))`

Is there an xarray method that can select from this format?

Thank you

Comment: The _time interval_ `slice('2021-05-09T0:05:00','2021-05-09T0:05:20')` is not within _9-5-2021 5am to 17-5-2021 12:20pm_.

Comment: _1pm-120pm , 4-420pm_ are not _4 hour time_ apart.

Answer (score 1):

> 5am-520am, 9am-920am , 1pm-120pm …4 hour time between intervals for 20 minutes each

You can use [xarray.Dataset.where](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.where.html):

```
file_dataset.where((file_dataset.time.dt.hour%4 == 1) & (file_dataset.time.dt.minute <= 20), drop=True)
```